# certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1123), api.covid19api.com

Tags: python, api, certificate, ssl-certificate, verify

I want to get data from api.covid19api.com
The following code did work some time ago:

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.covid19api.com")
payload = ''
headers = {}
conn.request("GET", "/countries", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read().decode('UTF-8')
existingCountries = json.loads(data)
existingCountries
dfC=pd.DataFrame(existingCountries)
dfC.head()
```

However, today I get the follwing error message:

SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 4 conn.request("GET", "/countries", payload, headers)
...
SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1123)

Can you help me, please?

Comment: The computer clock works fine besides different time zone (CET).

Comment: The following solution worked for me, too. Thank you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69550170/14106078